# How to get azure pipeline variable in task result?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have a pipeline part like following:

```
stages:
 - stage: A
   jobs:
     - job: build
       steps:
         - script: docker image build repo/myimage:1
         - script: docker  push repo/myimage:1
```

And I want to add a new step to check if "`repo/myimage:1`" pushed to repo as success.
So I read that "`docker image inspect repo/myimage:1`"  returns a result "1" or "0". if 0 success.

How can I add this step and check in pipeline? If docker inspect returns 1, build pipeline should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the failOnStderr

```
stages:
 - stage: A
   jobs:
     - job: build
       steps:
         - script: docker image build repo/myimage:1
         - script: docker push repo/myimage:1
         - script: docker image inspect repo/myimage:1
           failOnStderr: true
```

This parameter will fail the step if anything is written to the Standard Error (Stderr). If docker image inspect command fails, it writes the error to Stderr, so the step will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add this step and check in pipeline? If docker inspect returns 1, build pipeline should fail.

You can add a **bash** task in devops, after `docker inspect` related command, check return code if it's 1(non-zero), fail the task with logging command `echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"`

```
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          docker image inspect ....  # the related command which will return code.
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
              echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
          fi
```